# Design Pattern to replace nested loops

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

Is there any design pattern or some other way to replace the huge number of nested loops?
The only purpose is performance enhancement.

e.g

```
for (int i=0; i<2000; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<2000; j++)
    {
       for (int k=0; k<2000; k++)
       {

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing in the loops?

Comment: Are you using this algo to search something ?

Comment: design patterns will likely not improve performance, the performance will only improve if you improve the algorithm. Design patterns could actually hurt performance due to the overhead of stack switches etc.

Answer (score 5):

In general no. A design pattern is more about how you organise your code to make it comprehensible, maintainable extensible etc. By virtue of this, you might end up with more efficient code but not necessarily.

If your algorithm requires that you visit every element in a 3 dimensional data structure of size 2000, then no design pattern can help, you just have a n^3 algorithm and there's nothing you can do about this.

The only scope for improvement will be if your algorithm turns out to be naive and maybe visits more elements than is strictly required. harrisunderwork above alludes to this by asking if you are searching; if so, maybe there search algorithm can be made more efficient but again, this is not a question regarding design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int x=0; x < 2000*2000*2000; x++)
{
    // you can calculate here real values of i,j,k if you need this for smth
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You can't use this logic to search in a 3 dimensional datatype.

Comment: your x value will get infinite or negative after iterating 25% of items, because int is 32 bit, and means around 2*10^9(signed as you selecting) but you iterating up to 8*10^9

Comment: @Saeed - your comment is dependent on language and machine architecture, which were not specified.